# Fine-tuning tooltip position in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tooltip

When the tooltip is activated on a geographical layer it pops up with **the cursor on the top-left corner of the label** thus covering part of it.

Is there any way to fine-tune this behaviour (*without rewriting a select tool in python*)?

Comment: Appending characters on the left ... ?

Comment: I would add the following : when the tooltip pops up **zooming on the map** (with mouse wheel) **is impossible** ... you have to move the cursor so that the label disappear and the scrolling gets possible again ... is this behaviour only bugging me ? I find that sooo annoying ...

Answer (score -1):

Add a paragraph break to the HTML Map Tip text

Open Layer Properties > Display and type `<p>` in the start of HTML Map Tip box.

Comment: That way you change the content of the tooltip _not its positioning_ (left topmost corner of the tooltip  remain under the cursor ...)

Comment: Doesn't resolve the question.